# How to create a NSInputStream/NSOutputStream pair by accepting a server socket?

Tags: tcp, nsstream, nsinputstream, nsoutputstream, cfstream

I know that you can create a `NSInputStream` and `NSOutputStream` pair (toll-free bridged to `CFReadStream`, `CFWriteStream`) by opening a TCP client connection using [`CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStreamConstants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost) according to the [Stream Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html).

How can one create a TCP *server* that listens on a port and accepts a connection as a `NSInputStream` and `NSOutputStream` pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RemoteCurrency sample project provides an example of this in [QServer.m](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/RemoteCurrency/Listings/Libraries_QServer_m.html) (previously known as TCPServer.m). The sample code is actually for setting up Bonjour advertising, but that part can be excluded for a simple TCP server.

You create a **socket** with your own accept callback by calling [`CFSocketCreate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSocketRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/CFSocketCreate), **bind** and **listen** to a port by calling [`CFSocketSetAddress`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSocketRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/CFSocketSetAddress), and start getting **accept** callbacks by calling [`CFSocketCreateRunLoopSource`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSocketRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/CFSocketCreateRunLoopSource) followed by [`CFRunLoopAddSource`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFRunLoopAddSource).

Then, in the accept callback, you create `NSInputStream`/`NSOutputStream` pair from the connection handle using [`CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStreamConstants/#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket), set the input stream’s delegate and start receiving **recv** callbacks by calling [`scheduleInRunLoop:forMode:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSStream/scheduleInRunLoop:forMode:), and then [`open`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSStream/open) both streams to start using them.

Using [NSInputStream](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInputStream_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSInputStream) and [NSOutputStream](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSOutputStream_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSOutputStream) abstractions (as opposed to creating a new thread and calling the standard UNIX functions `socket`, `bind`, `listen`, `accept`, `send`, `recv`) allows one to easily receive network events in the same NSRunLoop as the rest of the run-loop based APIs on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

I have a sample app that you can download that creates a pair of NSStreams connected through a socket. It then streams picture-perfect, real-time video through the sockets using the camera on an iOS device:

The code is concise, and simple-to-follow (ignore the extra files in the project; NavController.h/m and PeerConnectionViewController.h/m and CameraViewController.h/m are the only three files of relevance):

https://app.box.com/s/fnim5ril4mzu518wj98zy3ah8l83jayv